# Statistical test for comparing two frequencies with R

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, frequency

i have this situation. A set of 5000 objects, 4950 blue and 50 green. From this set two people (person A and person B) fish separately 100 objects each and i would like to know if one of the two people has tricked me (not fishing blinded).

- person A fished one set of 100 objects, 90 blue and 10 green.
- person B fished one set of 100 objects, 99 blue and 1 green (that would be expected by chance)

Which test should i use? Could someone point me to a R example/solution about it?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can present your data as a contingency table, in this case a $2\times 2$ table of counts, with rows indexed by person (A or B) and columns indexed by color. Then you can use a chi-square test of independence.